# shell script, replace .png with @2x.png

Tags: macos, shell

I need a scrip to replace .png with @2x.png How can I do this for all file names in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming bash:

```
for f in *.png; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.png}@2x.png"
done
```

---

### Explanation:

#### Line 1:

```
for f in *.png; do
```

For loop. Iterates over all filenames in the current directory that match the glob pattern `*.png`, sets `$f` to each name in turn, and executes the body of the loop.

#### Line 2:

```
mv "$f" "${f%.png}@2x.png"
```

Executes the `mv` tool. The first arg is just `"$f"`, which is the file you want to rename. The second arg is a two-step process:

1. `${f%.png}` evaluates to the filename with the extension `.png` stripped off.
2. Following the stripped filename is `@2x.png`, which just appends that string back onto the filename.

#### Line 3:

```
done
```

Terminates the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.png
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    filename="${filename}@2x.png"
    mv "$file" "$filename"
done
```